# Specific field in table to update when query runs

Tags: mysql

I run an append query to update tblProjectTracking. Sometimes the status from the source of my query changed from Pending to Approved. When I run my append query, it adds new projects, but doesn't update the status on the old projects. Is there a way for my project status in tblProjectTracking to reflect the new status pulled by the query without me creating a make table, making a copy of the make table, and renaming it to tblProjectTracking?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: The complete answer to the question as asked is **YES**

Comment: If you would like more details..... **so would we**

Comment: I was hoping you woudl take the hint and add some code so we could see what you are doing and therefore be able to give a sensible answer. However as you have not I am off